# Can I start a game on one PC and continue on another?

Tags: a-dark-room

In [A Dark Room](http://adarkroom.doublespeakgames.com/) is it possible to start the game on one PC/browser and then continue it on another? Are there perhaps files I can copy from one machine to another to continue elsewhere?

*Edit* I'm using Firefox as my browser

Comment: This should be possible but have to look into it. Which browser do you use? I think you should look into copying your browser cookies to another PC. These can often be found in a hidden folder under user\appdata

Comment: Here is how you transfer your user profile (including cookies) with chrome: http://superuser.com/questions/367741/how-do-i-transfer-my-google-chrome-profile-to-a-new-pc

Comment: Forgot to specify browser, sorry. I'm using Firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As of October 2013](http://blog.doublespeakgames.com/?p=31), A Dark Room officially supports importing and exporting saved games. There is a `save` link in the bottom right corner that will let you copy or paste your current game state as a base64-encoded string:

[image]

No more need to mess with the console! Just copy and paste away!

Answer (score 9):

A Dark Room uses `localStorage` for saving, so these steps will work in all browsers:

1. Open the JavaScript console. If you don't know how, see [this post on Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).
2. To save, type

   ```
   JSON.stringify(localStorage);
   ```

   in the console and copy the output. (It will be VERY long. **Important**: Remember not to copy the quotation marks at the beginning and end!) This is now your save string.
3. To load a saved game, first type

   ```
   var storage =
   ```

   and then paste your save string. Then, paste this into the console:

   ```
   for (var x in storage) { localStorage.setItem(x, storage[x]); }
   ```

Comment: On Firefox, `CTRL+SHIFT+K` opens the JavaScript console

Comment: Hm, I have trouble reimporting this into Firefox, probably due to nested escaped quotes... I also tried `storage = JSON.parse(storageStringWithQuotationMarks)`, which somehow puts parentheses around the whole dict, i.e. something like `({gameState:"{\"version\":` etc. and your `for` loop yields an `undefined`

Comment: There is a little mistake; in last line try: `for (var x in storage) { localStorage.setItem(x, storage[x]); }`

Comment: With the source [made available](http://blog.doublespeakgames.com/?p=21) now, one could of course use the actual [`loadGame`](https://github.com/Continuities/adarkroom/blob/master/script/engine.js#L150) function to load the game, which boils down to `State = JSON.parse(gameState)` (where `gameState` was obtained via `localStorage.gameState`) and `Engine.upgradeState();`

Comment: @surfrider Whoops, typo. Fixed.

Comment: Also, you need to do it rather quickly. If the game does an autosave during the var storage + paste part and the for part, your game won't load.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have looked up how to copy your profile on firefox. Make sure you can see hidden files and folders. Then in the appdata in the users map something like (c:\users\'yourname'\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\firefox) you find a profiles map. You can try to copy this when you finished with the game and paste it on another PC to continue. I am not sure this works but the game is most probably storing stuff through php sessions which end up in the cookies file.

You could also go deeper into the map structure and just copy the cookies file. I found cookies.sqlite. There are also extensions to import and export cookies like this one: https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/cookies-exportimport/.