# How does saving in A Dark Room work?

Tags: a-dark-room

I've been playing [A Dark Room](http://adarkroom.doublespeakgames.com/index.html), and have noticed that the game auto-saves. While this is great, it means I can't play my save on another device, presumably because it saves to my cookies or IP. I've gotten as far as The Dusty Path, but cannot seem to navigate it on my tablet. If I go to my laptop to continue, will my progress be lost? If so, is there any way to preserve it?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/121651/42984

Comment: @DavidStarkey how do you open the console on Chrome on iPad?

Comment: That is an excellent question, and I see [you have asked it](http://superuser.com/questions/614671/how-do-you-open-the-developers-console-on-chrome-on-an-ipad).  I do not have an iPad so I cannot answer this but best of luck to you.